# Calling delete on a pointer to an int

Tags: c++, pointers

Suppose I have this simple program:

```
int main()
{
    int myInt = 12;
    int* intPtr = &myInt;//alias
    std::cout << *intPtr << "\n";

    delete intPtr; //This statement makes the program crash, why?

    return 0;
}
```

My question is the comment in the above program.

My guess regarding what's possibly causing the crash is that when `myInt` goes out of scope, when the program finishes, it is removed from the stack, but the memory has already been deleted, but I am not sure.

Comment: Perhaps because you haven't new-ed it. It is pointing to a stack variable. You don't delete a pointer for which you haven't allocated memory dynamically through new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it is because the runtime uses some data structure to store information about all the blocks of memory that have been dynamically allocated. When you call `delete` on a pointer, the runtime looks up the pointer in the data structure and marks the corresponding block of memory freed somehow. The runtime typically won't check that the pointer you pass in really was allocated with `new`: that's your responsibility as the programmer to ensure. If you violate the precondition of `delete`, then the memory management algorithm does something unpredictable, and when something unpredictable happens involving memory, the result is often a crash.

This is a good example of undefined behaviour. The runtime *could* check that the pointer was allocated with `new`, but that would slow down the program. Allowing some things to be undefined behaviour makes it possible to generate more efficient code.

Answer (score 1):

Using `delete` on anything other than a pointer returned from `new` is Undefined Behavior.
Using `delete[]` on anything other than a pointer returned from `new[]` is UB.
Using `free` on anything other than a pointer returned from `malloc` is UB.

Valgrind and other memory sanitizers can often detect this kind of issue, but if your program has good design (use more smart pointers!) it tends not to happen anyway.